# entity framework, WCF and user permissions: how to implement it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, permissions

I have an application that use a library for the repository to do all the operations on the database. This library has many methods, and some users would have permissions to do all the operations but others not.

I have a client application, that if it is installed on a computer inside the LAN, this client directly uses the repository to connect to the database. This way, for performance reasons, the client does not to have pass through the WCF host.

If the application is installed on a computer outside the LAN, then it connects through the WCF service, and then uses the repository to connect to the database.

My question is **how to check if a user has permission to execute a repository method**.

I am thinking of two options. One is when I create an object in the repository, it is created when I start the application and destroyed when I close the application. When I create the repository, I get all the permissions configuration for all the users, so I execute only one query on the database. However, if the application is very big or I have a lot of users, this can consume a lot of memory, which is not good.

The other option is, for each method on the repository, pass two additional arguments, the user and the password, so the first thing each method does is to query to the database for the permission. This consumes less memory, but makes more queries to the database. The query is very simple, but consumes resources (connections).

So I would like to know if there are more options to control the permissions or whether my first option is a good solution.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, in my future questions I will follow this recomendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is a password or unique access key which is the second choice like using a GUID or something. You would need single persistence object serving multiple requests. Creating and destroying on every connection seems useless. Single object, multiple connection, multiple keys for multiple projects. Keep track of all the keys for the objects. It is give and take in terms of resources.